# I uninstalled skype, and still have an icon in my application menu called "skype"

Tags: uninstall, icons, skype, appmenu

thanks in advance for your help. This problem initially started when I noticed two "skype" icons in my applications. I thought I'd uninstall and reinstall to remove the eyesore, but only one disappeared, and the other is now an icon that looks like a white sheet of paper, but it is still called "skype." Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use:

```
sudo apt-get remove
```

in order to uninstall skype?

Perhaps something is not been deleted as it should be.

Try to run this instead:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove <program name>
```

Then reboot the system. I suggest you to install BleachBit to clean your OS.

Check your Home if something is still there, press: CTRL + H to see hidden folders, and erase everything that has skype in it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to remove `skype-bin` too:

```
sudo apt purge skype-bin
```